# Alterar os valores máximos em um gráfico de barra no Seaborn(barplot)

Tags: python, data.frame, gráfico, ipython-notebook, seaborn

Quando eu vou "plotar" um gráfico de barra ele modifica os meus valores no eixo Y de maneira proporcional , mas eu quero que fiquem com os valores reais que eles tem no dataset, como altero essa configuração?

dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/gregorut/videogamesales

```
dados_vendas_Activision = dados.query("Publisher=='Activision'").query("Year>=2000")
dados_vendas_Activision_2012 = dados_vendas_Activision.query("Year==2012")
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
sns.barplot(data=dados_vendas_Activision_2012,
            x='Platform',
            y='Global_Sales',
            ci=None)
```

[image: NO eixo Y os valores aparentemente ficaram de forma proporcional, no lugar dele me retornar o valor das vendas totais ele me retorna a proporcionalidade acerca do todo de um valor aprentemente]

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa recuperar a instância do objeto do tipo [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#the-axes-class), que representa os eixos do gráfico por meio do método [`matplotlib.pyplot.gca()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html).

O objeto `Axes` possui dois métodos: [`Axes.set_xlim()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-xlim) e [`Axes.set_ylim()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-ylim), capazes de configurar os limites dos eixos x e y, respectivamente.

Veja só um exemplo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xmax = 10
ymax = 5

dados = {
    'PS3' : 2.0,
    'X360': 1.75,
    'PC'  : 1.70,
    'Wii' : 0.75,
    'PSV' : 1.60,
    '3DS' : 0.25,
    'DS'  : 0.33,
    'WiiU': 0.25
}

# Configura os eixos
eixos = plt.gca()
eixos.set_xlim([-0.5, xmax + 0.5])
eixos.set_ylim([0, ymax])

plt.bar(*zip(*dados.items()))
plt.show()
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mas não teria como o valor das colunas seguir essa proporcionalidade também? por exemplo , já que o valor máximo do eixo Y aumentou em 2.5 vezes o valor da "barra" do PS3 ir para 5 também?